# List of programs for post-CCSD(T) calculations

Tags: software, quantum-chemistry, software-recommendations, one-topic-per-answer, coupled-cluster

Implementations of CCSD(T) are almost too numerous to list, but CCSDT and CCSDT(Q) are much more rare. I have compiled a list of such programs below, and I would be interested to hear if anyone is aware of more.

- MRCC: Supports arbitrary order CC and CC() methods.
- NWchem: Supports CCSDT and CCSDTQ. No CCSDT(Q).
- CFOUR: Supports CCSDT. CCSDT(Q) and CCSDTQ are "not part of the public release", whatever that means.
- CC(t;3) PSI4 Plugin: Can perform CCSDT. No parallelization, AFAIK. Appears to be unmaintained, but still works.
- GAMESS-US: Can perform CCSDT.
- Aquarius: Uses the Cyclops Tensor Framework. Can do CCSDT, CCSDT(Q) and CCSDTQ. Lightly documented.

Answer (score 1):

Also ORCA can perform that type of calculation.
You can check it on [this link](https://www.orcasoftware.de/tutorials_orca/react/actibar.html)

Comment: This link seems to point to ORCA being able to perform CCSD(T) calculations. As the question mentions, this is fairly common and they are looking for programs that can go beyond this, e.g. CCSDT, which fully includes triple excitations rather than just perturbative triples like in CCSD(T). Even if it were a fit, we generally like to avoid link only answers. See some of the answers under [this tag](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-topic-per-answer) that give fairly detailed answers to "big list" questions.